# Class reference grants access to private member

Tags: c++, templates, private-members

I was writting a class for 'turning' modes on-off easily, then I got a bit confused. On the overloaded operator= to copy from another class, access to the private `T` member `m_Mode`is granted, why does this happen? Is it sandard, or perhaps a compiler bug?

```
template<class T>
class CFixedMode
{
private:
    T m_Mode;
public:
    CFixedMode()
    {
        m_Mode = static_cast<T>(0);
    }
    ~CFixedMode(){}
    void            SetMode( T mode );
    void            SetNotMode( T mode );
    BOOL            IsMode( T mode );
    CFixedMode<T>&              operator=( const CFixedMode< T >& rFixedMode );
};

template<class T>void CFixedMode<T>::SetMode( T mode )
{
    m_Mode |= mode;
}
template<class T>void CFixedMode<T>::SetNotMode( T mode )
{
    m_Mode &= (~mode);
}
template<class T>BOOL CFixedMode<T>::IsMode( T mode )
{
    return ( ( m_Mode & mode ) == mode ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
template<class T>CFixedMode<T>& CFixedMode<T>::operator =( const CFixedMode<T>& rFixedMode )
{
    if( typeid( m_Mode ) == typeid( rFixedMode.m_Mode ) )
        m_Mode = rFixedMode.m_Mode;
    return *this;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CFixedMode<DWORD> Mode;
    DWORD rMode = 0x00000010;
    Mode.SetMode( rMode );

    CFixedMode<DWORD> Mode2;
    Mode2 = Mode;
    if( Mode2.IsMode( 0x00000010 ) )
    {
        //cout << Mode2.m_Mode; //c2248
        cout << "True" << endl;
    }

    typeid(Mode).before(typeid(CFixedMode<DWORD>));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `operator=` only accepts the same type for T, meaning it's the same class and thus has accessibility to the private members.

Comment: So the entire `typeid` thing isn't even necessary? But then it's standard right?

Comment: Correct, since you only accept the same template instantiation for the parameter, that `typeid` comparison should always be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private means that it's private to the *class*, not to *instances* of the class.  Private is used to hide implementation details, so it makes sense that an object of the same type can access private members of other objects. Those other objects have the same implementation, so there's no point in hiding details.

By the way, your operator= should check for self assignment.  (Or, as Chris pointed out, you could use the copy and swap idiom.)  And, you don't need to check the types with typeid.

Comment: Hmm this actually explains why there is sometimes `const` to overloaded operators

Comment: Or you could consider implementing copy-swap.

Comment: @ViniyoShouta Not sure how const directly comes into play here?  const is used with overloaded operators when you want to be able to do the operator on a const value or reference.  For example, `const Obj a = ...; Obj b = ...; Obj c = a + b;` Wouldn't compiler if a const operator+ wasn't defined.

Comment: @Corbin, if `const` wasnt specified at `operator=` I could change the reference value. `rFixedMode.m_Mode = 0;`

Comment: @ViniyoShouta Oh, I thought you meant the actual overloads are const, not the rhs argument.  Yes, the rhs argument should always be const.  It would be a weird, weird side affect if operator= could mutate the right hand side.  I believe the const is actually required to be standards conforming (am not 100% sure though).

Comment: yep, tested and it does chances the reference value. bit of a weapon eh.

Comment: @ViniyoShouta Interesting.  I also just checked, and I believe it's not required by the standard to be const.  I suppose that makes sense though since C++ loves to let you do basically anything possible.  I suppose the consumer of the class would be theoretically responsible for knowing that it mutates the rhs (and the author would be responsible for making that odd decision, and hopefully documenting the hell out of it).

Comment: @ViniyoShouta One more thing about the const reference argument: if it were a non-const reference, you wouldn't be able to use temporary values on the RHS.